# Python - Fastest Way to Search Hundreds of Thousands/Millions of Records Against Hundreds of Thousands/Millions of Records?

Tags: python, mysql, query-optimization

I have a Python program that will take any number of addresses in one database table (Dataset A) and query each one against another database table that contains promotional pricing for addresses across the country (Dataset B).  The purpose of this program is to see which addresses in Dataset A are in Dataset B, and if they are, indicate that it found it and also the record ID in the table.  I have a set series of wildcard queries to do the SQL searching in a certain order to pull results, which is part of the problem since I do wildcard searches with LIKE ‘%CRITERIA%’, which slows things down tremendously despite everything being indexed in MySQL.

Here's an example type of search that it does today…let’s say the input address in Dataset A is 123 Main Street, Brooklyn, NY 11201 but the address in Dataset B is 123 North Main Street, Brooklyn, NY 11201.  Doing a straight query of Dataset A against Dataset B would not find a match since it’s not an exact match, but doing a wildcard search would yield a possible valid result with this style of query:

SELECT *
FROM Dataset_B
WHERE House_Number = 123 AND Street Like ‘%Main%’ AND City = ‘Brooklyn’ AND State = ‘NY’

I skipped the zip code since sometimes that interferes with results since they commonly have the incorrect zip code on them, but doing a zip code search later would be a secondary search if I didn’t find a hit using the above.

After my program receives the query results, it conducts an analysis to make sure that the result for each entry is not a false positive.

I’ve been using a Python multiprocessing SQL that I developed for this purpose and it’s worked pretty well overall, but I’m not sure how resource efficient it is compared to alternatives.  It commonly takes up 100% of the hard drive datarate due to all this wildcard querying with up to 8 concurrent queries running at once to take advantage of all of my cores.  The problem occurs when Dataset A is hundreds of thousands, or millions of entries where it can take up to 12 hours or more since the data in Dataset B could also be hundreds of thousands, or millions of records.  I feel like SQL is the slowest way to do this though and am not sure if there’s a much more efficient solution using Python datastructures to do this including my wildcard criteria?  Pandas would probably be overwhelmed by this volume and I’m not sure how much faster it would be compared to SQL.  I was playing around with trying to use NumPy but wasn’t sure if that was the right direction.  Can someone provide some guidance on the fastest way to tackle this kind of problem?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TAB:LE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  Also, do you know about `FULLTEXT`; it would facilitate searching for "words" much faster.

Comment: With "hard drive", you mean HDD, no SSD?

Comment: Do you do wildcard searches only on the street name, or on other columns? Also you said you indexed "everything" but be specific and show your table DDL. We need to know what you tried. A compound index can help the query case you show, but if you have other cases we can't guess at them.

Comment: What do you mean by "search against"? Please read [ask] and [mre], and show an example of what the code actually needs to do - a small sample of the input, and exactly what the output should be, with some concrete explanation of the logic.

Comment: have you considered trying to normalize the data before you try to compare it?  https://github.com/datamade/usaddress for example.  also, sphinx say they fulltext search faster than mysql alone http://sphinxsearch.com/info/powered/